# A sourceless vector field tangent to the boundary of a volume integrates to be zero

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

This is an exercise of vector calculus.
Let $V$ be a volume with boundary $\partial V$ , and let $\textbf{F}$ be a vector field on $V$. Prove the following result by writing the $i^{th}$ component of the integrand as the divergence of a suitable vector field, then using the divergence theorem.
If $\nabla \cdot \textbf{F}=0$ in $V$ and $\textbf{F} \cdot \textbf{n}=0$ on $\partial V$, then $\int_V \textbf{F}dV=0$.

How can the conditions given be used?

Answer (score 0):

Hint. Consider the vector field $x_i\textbf{F}$. Then by divergence theorem,
$$\int_V\nabla \cdot (x_i\mathbf{F})\,dV=\int_{\partial V}(x_i\mathbf{F})\cdot \textbf{n}\,dS.$$
Now apply the product rule for divergence: $\nabla \cdot (x_i\mathbf{F})=x_i  \nabla \cdot \mathbf{F}+ F_i$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: I got it, thank you!

Comment: Since you are new here, I recommend a short tour: https://math.stackexchange.com/tour